# ORA-00900 error while inserting

Tags: sql, oracle, ant, sql-insert

I am running below Oracle SQL from Ant script.

```
INSERT INTO Prv_ProcessValidation_S (
         Prv_ID, 
         Prv_PROCESSNAME,
         Prv_DESCRIPTION, 
         Prv_VALIDATIONDECISIONNAME) 
  values ('56B456058B9C44BD8B78AA5107093E39',
          'CaseIssue',
          'Selected Plan is not available for this state',
          'PlanAvailabilityDecision')
```

It is throwing this error.

```
[sql] java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

When I run the SQL from SQL Developer it is running correctly. I did not find any valid solution for this problem. Can anyone please help me on this?

Below is the Ant script. The only mentioned SQL is failing but all the other SQL are running correctly.

```
<sql
    driver="${database.driver}"
    url="${database.url}"
    userid="${database.user}"
    password="${database.password}"
    onerror="continue"
    >
    ${sql.toRun}
    <classpath>
      <fileset dir="${script.root}/lib">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
      </fileset>
    </classpath>
</sql>
```

Comment: May be give a try using bind variable and then pass to insert statement. Am not sure for Java, Its just a guess

Comment: If query is working on sql developer then show us the java code

Comment: So how does your Ant script look like?

Comment: maybe a semicolon is missing at the end.

Comment: Added the Ant code I am using. I cross-checked there is no issue with the semicolon.